# How to check if a directory has write permissions in rust?

Tags: rust

I was wondering if there is a way to check if the rust application has permission to write inside a folder?

I saw there was a way to check it by reading the raw bits permission, but this doesn't take the user or group into account. Another way could be to write a file and see if it fails, but that doesn't sound very elegant.

So far I have tried this, but it seems like it only works for files (?)

```rust
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let loc = "/var/log/myfolder";

    // Check if able to write inside directory
    let res = File::options()
              .read(false)
              .write(true)
              .open(loc);

    if res.is_ok() {
        println!("No read permission");
    } else {
        println!("Read permission");
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way to check if a folder has write permissions without trying to create a file inside it?

Comment: _that doesn't sound very elegant_ It is however the only correct answer here, because whatever check you perform before trying, the state of the filesystem can change between the check operation and the write operation.

Comment: There is a myriad of reasons why writing to a directory could fail. Checking permissions in advance is complex, but still covers only a tiny fraction of possible errors you could encounter, and as mentioned it's also subject to race conditions. The only correct approach is trying to perform whatever action you want to perform, and dealing with the error after the fact. So you shouldn't write a new file to check whether you have permission; instead, you should write the _actual_ file(s) to the directory, and deal with the errors once they happen.

Comment: I see your point, but in some cases you may not want to write a file right away, but just check if it's writable. The solution I have done so far is to write a file to a directory, see if it fails and then delete it if it worked. This solution misses my original question a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`fs::metadata`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.metadata.html):

```
use std::fs;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let loc = "/etc/";

    // Check if able to write inside directory
    let md = fs::metadata(loc)?;
    let permissions = md.permissions();
    let readonly = permissions.readonly();
    if readonly {
        println!("No write permission");
    } else {
        println!("Write permission");
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

On a Unix-like system you can get more specific information with the [`PermissionsExt` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.PermissionsExt.html):

```
use std::fs;
// make sure to import the trait
use std::os::unix::fs::PermissionsExt;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let loc = "/etc/";

    // Check if able to write inside directory
    let md = fs::metadata(loc)?;
    let permissions = md.permissions();
    let mode = permissions.mode();
    println!("{:o}", mode); // 40755
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Hmm, are there no way to check the owner (user and group) of the directory?

Comment: @Typewar There is, using the [`MetadataExt` trait's](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.MetadataExt.html#) [`uid`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.MetadataExt.html#tymethod.uid) and [`gid`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.MetadataExt.html#tymethod.gid) methods, respectively. What their permissions are is already contained in the `mode` bits though, see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.MetadataExt.html#tymethod.mode.

Comment: @isaactfa Your bit about the mode bits isn't true. It just returns the `chmod` mode bits as-is, so you won't know whether to test the user, group, or other access bits without knowing the owning user+group. Also this answer doesn't take into account ACLs.